# Why does the wrong message appear with jQuery Validation?

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using jQuery validation with 2 custom methods and one standard `required:true` method to validate a date. One custom method makes sure the date is in the future, the other gives a dynamic message if the date is outside a chosen interval. For instance if the chosen interval is 7 days and the date chosen is beyond that, the error message would prompt the user to choose a date within that 7 day interval.

The methods all function properly but the messages don't display in the correctly. If I choose a date outside the interval, the `required:true` message displays. If I choose a date within the interval to pass validation, then choose a date outside again it displays the correct message. I've tried reordering the rules but it behaves the same.

Is there some way that the rules can cascade into the correct messages?

```
$('form[name="returnapplyForm"]').validate({
 rules: {
   returnappfrmnextPayDate :{
     within_interval: true,
     dateForward:true,
     required: true
   }
},
messages: {
 returnappfrmnextPayDate : {
   required: "Please enter your next pay date."
 }
}
```

The custom method that makes sure the date is within the specified interval. It's dynamic

```
$.validator.addMethod('within_interval', function(value, element) {
        //foo
}, function() {return 'Your next Pay Date should be within ' + dateError + ' days from today.'});
```

And the date forward validator:

```
$.validator.addMethod("dateForward", function(value, element) {
     // bar
}, "Please enter a valid date in the future.");
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question, but why not use a datepicker and only allow dates in the range to be selected?

Comment: That looks like a great solution for this application, thank you for that. I have other fields that are giving me the same type of problem when multiple rules are present and I want to be able to display the correct reason for the validation failure.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?